# How to search a Mysql table which contains 150+ columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I know this is a very poor database design,but still i want to know is there any way to search a keyword in all the columns in that table through Mysql query(not Php)?

I've searched in internet but didn't find any help regarding this? if nothing such possibilty is there,then i think dividing the table is only the option left

Comment: Of course this is possible, using 150+ `OR` in your sql query : `where  field1 like '%keyword%' OR field2 like '%keyword%' OR field3 like '%keyword%'` and so on... of course this is a very ugly query, but you seem to have a very ugly database design, so no miracles !

Comment: Thanks,but i know that, i am asking for any other alternative

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use wildcards and anything like that on column names. Either select all columns with `*`or name the ones you need.

You could use dynamic SQL to patch your query together but this will probably only give you more problems handling it.

Comment: do i need to write all the 150 col names

Comment: You dont have to HAND write them out.  You could query the table for its columns, then generate sql in a loop or cursor then execute the sql.